# R: ggplot2 ploting a map with error message and warning messga

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize the data on a map by using ggplot2

I follow the instruction on this website:https://socviz.co/maps.html. I imitate the example of gun-related suicide.

Code is as followed:

```
cancer$rate_cut=cut(cancer$rate,c(5,10,15,20,25,30))

county_map %>% sample_n(5)

orange_pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 6, name = "Oranges")
orange_pal
## [1] "#FEEDDE" "#FDD0A2" "#FDAE6B" "#FD8D3C" "#E6550D"
## [6] "#A63603"
orange_rev <- rev(orange_pal)
orange_rev
## [1] "#A63603" "#E6550D" "#FD8D3C" "#FDAE6B" "#FDD0A2"
## [6] "#FEEDDE"

can_p <- ggplot(data = county_full,
                mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat,
                              fill = cancer$rate_cut, 
                              group = group))

can_p1 <- can_p + geom_polygon(color = "gray90", size = 0.05) + coord_equal()

can_p2 <- can_p1 + scale_fill_manual(values = orange_pal)

can_p2 + labs(title = "Gun-Related Suicides, 1999-2015",
              fill = "Rate per 100,000 pop.") +
  theme_map() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

My data looks like this:

```
head(county_full)
     long      lat order  hole piece            group    id county_name rate
1 1225889 -1275020     1 FALSE     1 0500000US01001.1 01001        <NA>   NA
2 1235324 -1274008     2 FALSE     1 0500000US01001.1 01001        <NA>   NA
3 1244873 -1272331     3 FALSE     1 0500000US01001.1 01001        <NA>   NA
4 1244129 -1267515     4 FALSE     1 0500000US01001.1 01001        <NA>   NA
5 1272010 -1262889     5 FALSE     1 0500000US01001.1 01001        <NA>   NA
6 1276797 -1295514     6 FALSE     1 0500000US01001.1 01001        <NA>   NA
  count population rate_cut
1    NA         NA     <NA>
2    NA         NA     <NA>
3    NA         NA     <NA>
4    NA         NA     <NA>
5    NA         NA     <NA>
6    NA         NA     <NA>
```

Although here it is all NA, I do have the data below.

When I ran the code, R gave me an error message:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (191382): fill
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (191382): fill
Backtrace:
 1. (function (x, ...) ...
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
 9. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)
```

========================================================

Thanks for the comment and I modified the code by joining the data(cancer and county_map).I get the map but I also got a warning message.

The latest code is like this:

```
can_p <- ggplot(data = county_full,
                mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat,
                              fill = county_full$rate_cut, 
                              group = group))
can_p1 <- can_p + geom_polygon(color = "gray90", size = 0.05) + coord_equal()
can_p2 <- can_p1 + scale_fill_manual(values = orange_pal)
can_p2 + labs(title = "Cancer incidence, 1999-2015",
              fill = "Rate per 100,000 pop.") +
  theme_map() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")

Warning message:Use of `county_full$rate_cut` is discouraged. Use `rate_cut` instead.
```

Comment: It's probably because your `x` and `y` aesthetics are coming from `county_full` but your fill is coming from just `cancer`. Thins work better when all your data is coming from the same data.frame. Seeing a `$` inside an `aes()` is usually a danger area. Not sure what's in `county_full`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: "Your __cancer__ data looks like this:". But what does your __county_full__ data look like?

Comment: I guess you need to join the __county_full__ data with the __cancer__ data. You didn't show this code, or perhaps you didn't do that.

Comment: The second error is suggesting that in place of `fill = county_full$rate_cut,` you should use the name of the column only, so just `fill = rate_cut`.  More to the point, the data you posted is `cancer` and your data call in the `ggplot` function is `data = county_full`.  Is this another dataset, or did you mean to put `cancer` there instead?